# Paragraph Indentation in Custom Environments

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs

I have been having trouble getting paragraph indentation to work within a custom environment. `\setlength` is not setting the length of the indentations as I expected. There should be a hanging indent of 17pt for each paragraph (or, in this case, bibliography entry).

[image: Example]

Because all my citations are written longhand (I am not using any bib file), I am not using the bibliography environment (though if you believe there is a way to get the result desired using that environment, please let me know!)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{mybibliography}{
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\hangindent}{17pt}
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Bibliography}
    
    \begin{mybibliography}
    
    Jack Smith, `Hello World: An analysis of the origins of the universe' (2014) 44(3) \textit{Journal of Something} 45.
    
    Jack Smith, `Hello World: An analysis of the origins of the universe' (2014) 44(3) \textit{Journal of Something} 45.
        
    \end{mybibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `\hangindent` is reset at the end of each paragraph. You need to reinstate it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{mybibliography}
 {%
  \par
  \setlength{\parskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{17pt}}%
 }
 {\par}% <-- don't forget

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Bibliography}
    
\begin{mybibliography}
    
Jack Smith, `Hello World: An analysis of the origins of the universe'
  (2014) 44(3) \textit{Journal of Something} 45.

Jack Smith, `Hello World: An analysis of the origins of the universe'
  (2014) 44(3) \textit{Journal of Something} 45.
        
\end{mybibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much!